# Modify default browser behavior so that images load in max resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to modify my browser (Firefox Quantum 57.0.1, 64-bit) so that images open in max resolution rather than auto-scaling to fit the browser window when I navigate to an image URL.

My programming background does not include any web development so I wouldn't know where to start on this project; I've experimenting with the developer tools console as a starting point. Based on the readout from the dev tools console and  related posts here I am hypothesized that the HTML snippet `<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">` controls default auto-sizing that occurs when I open images. Is there a simple modification I can make to consistently open to max resolution instead of auto-sizing anytime I use the browser to look at a new image?

Am I on the right track? Can anyone provide some pointers? Is this a feasible browser modification?

*NB: apologies to the inevitable senior user editing this post for incorrect tags or nomenclature - I don't have any experience in*

Comment: I would imagine that user style sheets might come in handy here. Not sure if Firefox supports these, however.

Comment: You mean on your own browser?

Comment: @domsson Firefox does support CSS stylesheets using the [style editor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Style_Editor) tab in the developer tools console. Can you suggest a particular CSS stylesheet "rule" to implement the mod I described?

Comment: @VilleKoo Yeah -- I want to modify my browser so that it opens images in max resolution rather than auto-scaling them. Are dev tools the right place to start or I am totally off in that regard?

Comment: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/disable-image-auto-resize-in-firefox/ this seems to work

Comment: @VilleKoo it works! If you'd like to post the steps in an answer I'll mark it correct. Otherwise I'll self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Type about:config in the Firefox address bar
2. Search for browser.enable_automatic_image_resizing
3. Change it to false

[source](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/disable-image-auto-resize-in-firefox/)